# Convert first letter of given file to lower case

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to convert the 1st letter of each line to lower case up to the end of the file. How can I do this using shell scripting?

I tried this:

```
plat=`echo $plat |cut -c1 |tr [:upper:] [:lower:]``echo $plat |cut -c2-`
```

but this converts only the first character to lower case.

My file looks like this:

```
Apple
Orange
Grape
```

Expected result:

```
apple
orange
grape
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do that with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/./\L&/' Shell.txt
```

(Probably safer to do

```
sed -e 's/^./\L&\E/' Shell.txt
```

if you ever want to extend this.)

Comment: This converts all the first character into lower case but not replacing the old Caps strings in file. Is it possible to check for upper and replace accordingly in the same file

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. This does what your question says: "convert the 1st letter of each line to lower case up to the end of the file"

Comment: Is this POSIX sed or does it use a GNU extension? This didn't work for me on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
plat=`echo $plat |cut -c1 |tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'``echo $plat |cut -c2-`
```

Answer (score 2):

Pure Bash 4.0+ , parameter substitution:

```
>"$outfile"                         # empty output file
while read ; do
    echo "${REPLY,}" >> "$outfile"  # 1. character to lowercase
done < "$infile"  
mv "$outfile" "$infile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single sed command that uses only POSIX sed features:

```
sed -e 'h;s,^\(.\).*$,\1,;y,ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,;G;s,\
.,,'
```

These are two lines, the first line ending in a backslash to quote the newline character.